# AngularJS | Login Required ngMessage

Tags: angularjs

I'm wondering why my `required` messages are not hiding on load when a user first views my form?

My code is as per:

```
<div ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" class="form-input-error">
                <div class="message" ng-message="required">Please enter your username</div>
                <div class="message" ng-message="maxlength">Username is too long.</div>
            </div>
```

The `ng-message="maxlength"` doesn't appear until the requirement is met however, I don't understand why required is showing on load?

Ideally I would like the required message to display if the user tries to submit the form with none of the fields entered or if only one field has been entered. Essentially, meeting the required validation rules.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/beuL679o/16/) example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because angular validation will evaluate if the form meets the requirements on load and since there is no value in the required field then it's invalid. As the username is 0 characters it's less than the maxlength so that's valid.

By default for ng-messages angular will only show the first message that is invalid. In this case that is fine.

To prevent messages showing until submit is clicked you can set a scope property on submit and use a `ng-show` on the ng-messages to only show the validation message if submitted:

```
$scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    // Check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if (isValid) {
        alert('Form is valid');
    }
};
```

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-controller="LoginCtrl" novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="submitForm(loginForm.$valid)">
<div ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" class="form-input-error" ng-show="submitted">
    <div class="message" ng-message="required">Please enter your username</div>
    <div class="message" ng-message="maxlength">Username is too long.</div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud7aebzf/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that works great but I can't get the required error message to show if you click on the submit button when the inputs are empty?

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer - unfortunately, that's not working. With the submit set to $invalid - the form will register as valid and the alert will appear. I this may need to be set to $valid to check if form is valid on submit: http://jsfiddle.net/beuL679o/17/

Comment: I'll update it in a bit. I have to leave home. It should work.  There is something specific to your form that preventing it from working

Comment: Thanks for you help @Wayne Ellery. I'll look at what's going on and if I fix it, I will update the post.

Comment: It looks like the ng-message element needs to be present all the time and you can't use ng-show on ng-message so I needed to create a wrapping div.

Comment: Thanks @ Wayne, I didn't need the ng-show on the extra div. I moved it to the ng-messages div that's wrapping the inner error messages, this worked a treat: http://jsfiddle.net/beuL679o/20/ Would you like to edit your answer and I will mark it correct.